# Quantiles in rms' ols/cph

Tags: regression, quantile, rms

I need to conduct regression analyses with continuous and categorised data (as the latter is common in my field). So far, I used to do this as follows:

```
q <- lm(ep ~ cut2(exposure, g=5), data=data)
```

When I use the functions in the `rms` package, this doesn't seem to work:

```
q <- ols(ep ~ cut2(exposure, g=5), data=data)
```

and results in an error message (subscript out of bounds). It does work fine if I pre-define the quantiles, but this causes problems in the scripts I use.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: This question may be better asked on [stats.SE], as they generally are better versed in the ins and outs of R's sprawling package repositories.

Comment: Of course - I'm sorry!

Comment: Not to worry, I'm only looking to get this question to a place where it stands the best chance of being answered!